How to Ensure Responsive Image Stays on Top in a Text-Image Layout While Scrolling?
I'm developing a webpage featuring text on the left and an accompanying image on the right. As users scroll, the image dynamically adjusts based on the associated text. While the layout functions smoothly on desktop, I'm facing challenges with ensuring the image remains sticky and on top in responsive mode. Currently, when the screen size reduces, the image shifts below the text. Below is the code I'm working with:


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    const artwork = document.getElementById('artwork');
    const sections = document.querySelectorAll('.content-section');
    const screenWidth = window.innerWidth; // Get screen width

    const transformations = [
        { scale: 1, translateX: 0, translateY: 0 },        // Section 1
        { scale: 2.2, translateX: 60, translateY: -30 },  // Section 2
        { scale: 1.5, translateX: 20, translateY: 80 }, // Section 3
        { scale: 2, translateX: -100, translateY: -200 }  // Section 4
    ];

    const scrollHandler = () => {
        const scrollPosition = window.scrollY + window.innerHeight / 2;

        sections.forEach((section, index) => {
            const sectionTop = section.offsetTop;
            const sectionHeight = section.offsetHeight;

            if (scrollPosition > sectionTop && scrollPosition < sectionTop + sectionHeight) {
                const transform = transformations[index];
                artwork.style.transform = `scale(${transform.scale}) translate(${transform.translateX}px, ${transform.translateY}px)`;

                // Hide text on small screens
                if (screenWidth <= 768) {
                    section.style.display = 'none';
                }
            } else {
                // Restore text visibility
                section.style.display = 'block';
            }
        });
    };

    window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollHandler);
    scrollHandler(); // Initial call to set the correct transform on load
});
.imscroll {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
}

.grid-test {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    gap: 20px;
    width: 100%;
}

.text-section {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.interactive-container {
    position: sticky;
    top: 20px;
    height: 80vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 2; /* Increase z-index */
    padding-bottom: 20px; /* Add padding */
}

.interactive-container img {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    transition: transform 0.3s ease;
}

.content-section {
    padding: 20px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

/* Responsive Design */
/* Responsive Design */
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .grid-test {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .interactive-container {
        position: relative; /* Change position to relative */
        top: 0;
        height: auto; /* Reset height */
    }

.interactive-container img {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%; /* Make the image width 100% of its container */
    height: auto; /* Maintain aspect ratio */
    transition: transform 0.3s ease;
}

/* Responsive Design */
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .interactive-container {
        z-index: 2; /* Increase z-index */
        padding-bottom: 10px; /* Adjust padding for smaller screens */
    }
}
<div class="imscroll">
<div class="grid-test">


<div class="text-section">
<section class="content-section" id="section1">
<h2>Section 1</h2>

<p>Paragraph1 sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tempor nunc mauris, sit amet placerat tortor lobortis dapibus. Nam lectus eros, maximus ac magna vel, congue consequat eros. Fusce id pretium diam. Cras sit amet pharetra ante. Sed quis commodo quam, vel facilisis ipsum. Vestibulum sodales iaculis arcu, et fringilla nisi ullamcorper sed. Donec interdum sit amet est non accumsan. Donec non augue feugiat, fermentum nunc non, convallis est. Cras vel ligula nec odio faucibus ultricies. Sed vulputate tortor eget pretium convallis. Cras interdum elit eget mi porta suscipit. Morbi ut velit diam. Etiam finibus eros et efficitur rutrum. Quisque viverra metus ac eleifend imperdiet. Quisque pretium ut purus vitae tempus. Duis varius risus congue velit faucibus, sed interdum purus consectetur.</p>
</section>

<section class="content-section" id="section2">
<h2>Section 2</h2>

<p>Paragraph1 sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tempor nunc mauris, sit amet placerat tortor lobortis dapibus. Nam lectus eros, maximus ac magna vel, congue consequat eros. Fusce id pretium diam. Cras sit amet pharetra ante. Sed quis commodo quam, vel facilisis ipsum. Vestibulum sodales iaculis arcu, et fringilla nisi ullamcorper sed. Donec interdum sit amet est non accumsan. Donec non augue feugiat, fermentum nunc non, convallis est. Cras vel ligula nec odio faucibus ultricies. Sed vulputate tortor eget pretium convallis. Cras interdum elit eget mi porta suscipit. Morbi ut velit diam. Etiam finibus eros et efficitur rutrum. Quisque viverra metus ac eleifend imperdiet. Quisque pretium ut purus vitae tempus. Duis varius risus congue velit faucibus, sed interdum purus consectetur.</p>
</section>

<section class="content-section" id="section3">
<h2>Section 3</h2>

<p>Paragraph1 sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tempor nunc mauris, sit amet placerat tortor lobortis dapibus. Nam lectus eros, maximus ac magna vel, congue consequat eros. Fusce id pretium diam. Cras sit amet pharetra ante. Sed quis commodo quam, vel facilisis ipsum. Vestibulum sodales iaculis arcu, et fringilla nisi ullamcorper sed. Donec interdum sit amet est non accumsan. Donec non augue feugiat, fermentum nunc non, convallis est. Cras vel ligula nec odio faucibus ultricies. Sed vulputate tortor eget pretium convallis. Cras interdum elit eget mi porta suscipit. Morbi ut velit diam. Etiam finibus eros et efficitur rutrum. Quisque viverra metus ac eleifend imperdiet. Quisque pretium ut purus vitae tempus. Duis varius risus congue velit faucibus, sed interdum purus consectetur.</p>
</section>

<section class="content-section" id="section4">
<h2>Section 4</h2>

<p>Paragraph1 sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tempor nunc mauris, sit amet placerat tortor lobortis dapibus. Nam lectus eros, maximus ac magna vel, congue consequat eros. Fusce id pretium diam. Cras sit amet pharetra ante. Sed quis commodo quam, vel facilisis ipsum. Vestibulum sodales iaculis arcu, et fringilla nisi ullamcorper sed. Donec interdum sit amet est non accumsan. Donec non augue feugiat, fermentum nunc non, convallis est. Cras vel ligula nec odio faucibus ultricies. Sed vulputate tortor eget pretium convallis. Cras interdum elit eget mi porta suscipit. Morbi ut velit diam. Etiam finibus eros et efficitur rutrum. Quisque viverra metus ac eleifend imperdiet. Quisque pretium ut purus vitae tempus. Duis varius risus congue velit faucibus, sed interdum purus consectetur.</p>
</section>
</div>
  <div class="interactive-container">
<p style=" margin-top: 100px;"><img src="http://www.reedyrace.com/images/b64d-chassis.jpg" alt="Artwork" id="artwork" style=" border: 1px solid gray;" /></p>
</div>
</div>
</div>




First, you need some adjustments in CSS for smaller screens max-width: 768px.
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .grid-test {
        flex-direction: column-reverse; /* Switch order to keep image on top */
    }

    .interactive-container {
        height: 50vh; /* Adjust height for smaller screens */
        position: sticky;
    }

    .interactive-container img {
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
    }
}

In javascript remove this part.
if (screenWidth <= 768) {
    section.style.display = 'none';
}



document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    const artwork = document.getElementById('artwork');
    const sections = document.querySelectorAll('.content-section');
    const screenWidth = window.innerWidth; // Get screen width

    const transformations = [
        { scale: 1, translateX: 0, translateY: 0 },        // Section 1
        { scale: 2.2, translateX: 60, translateY: -30 },  // Section 2
        { scale: 1.5, translateX: 20, translateY: 80 }, // Section 3
        { scale: 2, translateX: -100, translateY: -200 }  // Section 4
    ];

    const scrollHandler = () => {
        const scrollPosition = window.scrollY + window.innerHeight / 2;

        sections.forEach((section, index) => {
            const sectionTop = section.offsetTop;
            const sectionHeight = section.offsetHeight;

            if (scrollPosition > sectionTop && scrollPosition < sectionTop + sectionHeight) {
                const transform = transformations[index];
                artwork.style.transform = `scale(${transform.scale}) translate(${transform.translateX}px, ${transform.translateY}px)`;
            } else {
                // Restore text visibility
                section.style.display = 'block';
            }
        });
    };

    window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollHandler);
    scrollHandler(); // Initial call to set the correct transform on load
});
.imscroll {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
}

.grid-test {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    gap: 20px;
    width: 100%;
}

.text-section {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.interactive-container {
    position: sticky; /* Keep position as sticky */
    top: 20px;
    height: 80vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 2; /* Maintain a higher z-index */
}

.interactive-container img {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    transition: transform 0.3s ease;
}

.content-section {
    padding: 20px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

/* Responsive Design */
/* Responsive Design */
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .grid-test {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .interactive-container {
        position: relative; /* Change position to relative */
        top: 0;
        height: auto; /* Reset height */
    }

.interactive-container img {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%; /* Make the image width 100% of its container */
    height: auto; /* Maintain aspect ratio */
    transition: transform 0.3s ease;
}

/* Responsive Design */
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .grid-test {
        flex-direction: column-reverse; /* Switch order to keep image on top */
    }

    .interactive-container {
        height: 50vh;
        position: sticky;
    }

    .interactive-container img {
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
    }
}
<div class="imscroll">
<div class="grid-test">


<div class="text-section">
<section class="content-section" id="section1">
<h2>Section 1</h2>

<p>Paragraph1 sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tempor nunc mauris, sit amet placerat tortor lobortis dapibus. Nam lectus eros, maximus ac magna vel, congue consequat eros. Fusce id pretium diam. Cras sit amet pharetra ante. Sed quis commodo quam, vel facilisis ipsum. Vestibulum sodales iaculis arcu, et fringilla nisi ullamcorper sed. Donec interdum sit amet est non accumsan. Donec non augue feugiat, fermentum nunc non, convallis est. Cras vel ligula nec odio faucibus ultricies. Sed vulputate tortor eget pretium convallis. Cras interdum elit eget mi porta suscipit. Morbi ut velit diam. Etiam finibus eros et efficitur rutrum. Quisque viverra metus ac eleifend imperdiet. Quisque pretium ut purus vitae tempus. Duis varius risus congue velit faucibus, sed interdum purus consectetur.</p>
</section>

<section class="content-section" id="section2">
<h2>Section 2</h2>

<p>Paragraph1 sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tempor nunc mauris, sit amet placerat tortor lobortis dapibus. Nam lectus eros, maximus ac magna vel, congue consequat eros. Fusce id pretium diam. Cras sit amet pharetra ante. Sed quis commodo quam, vel facilisis ipsum. Vestibulum sodales iaculis arcu, et fringilla nisi ullamcorper sed. Donec interdum sit amet est non accumsan. Donec non augue feugiat, fermentum nunc non, convallis est. Cras vel ligula nec odio faucibus ultricies. Sed vulputate tortor eget pretium convallis. Cras interdum elit eget mi porta suscipit. Morbi ut velit diam. Etiam finibus eros et efficitur rutrum. Quisque viverra metus ac eleifend imperdiet. Quisque pretium ut purus vitae tempus. Duis varius risus congue velit faucibus, sed interdum purus consectetur.</p>
</section>

<section class="content-section" id="section3">
<h2>Section 3</h2>

<p>Paragraph1 sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tempor nunc mauris, sit amet placerat tortor lobortis dapibus. Nam lectus eros, maximus ac magna vel, congue consequat eros. Fusce id pretium diam. Cras sit amet pharetra ante. Sed quis commodo quam, vel facilisis ipsum. Vestibulum sodales iaculis arcu, et fringilla nisi ullamcorper sed. Donec interdum sit amet est non accumsan. Donec non augue feugiat, fermentum nunc non, convallis est. Cras vel ligula nec odio faucibus ultricies. Sed vulputate tortor eget pretium convallis. Cras interdum elit eget mi porta suscipit. Morbi ut velit diam. Etiam finibus eros et efficitur rutrum. Quisque viverra metus ac eleifend imperdiet. Quisque pretium ut purus vitae tempus. Duis varius risus congue velit faucibus, sed interdum purus consectetur.</p>
</section>

<section class="content-section" id="section4">
<h2>Section 4</h2>

<p>Paragraph1 sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tempor nunc mauris, sit amet placerat tortor lobortis dapibus. Nam lectus eros, maximus ac magna vel, congue consequat eros. Fusce id pretium diam. Cras sit amet pharetra ante. Sed quis commodo quam, vel facilisis ipsum. Vestibulum sodales iaculis arcu, et fringilla nisi ullamcorper sed. Donec interdum sit amet est non accumsan. Donec non augue feugiat, fermentum nunc non, convallis est. Cras vel ligula nec odio faucibus ultricies. Sed vulputate tortor eget pretium convallis. Cras interdum elit eget mi porta suscipit. Morbi ut velit diam. Etiam finibus eros et efficitur rutrum. Quisque viverra metus ac eleifend imperdiet. Quisque pretium ut purus vitae tempus. Duis varius risus congue velit faucibus, sed interdum purus consectetur.</p>
</section>
</div>
  <div class="interactive-container">
<p style=" margin-top: 100px;"><img src="http://www.reedyrace.com/images/b64d-chassis.jpg" alt="Artwork" id="artwork" style=" border: 1px solid gray;" /></p>
</div>
</div>
</div>




Thankyou. it works great. Is there a way to still make it work without adding height on interactive container in responsive? My image cuts off in responsive. If I remove height, I cannot see text anymore. Thanks.
.interactive-container {
height: 50vh;

@newuser, You are welcome, so what is the height it should take?

I was hoping it can be auto based on screen size.
